# Google Test: variable number of parameters for tests in the same test case

Tags: c++11, googletest

I have just started studying a code base which uses Google Test as testing framework (which I am not familiar with). Parameterized tests are extensively used more or less in what I believe is the usual way:

```
class TestCaseName: public ::testing::TestWithParam<Params> {
    // fairly complex setup
}
TEST_P(TestCaseName, TestName) {...}
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(UniqueName, TestCaseName, CombinedInput);
```

The problem is that often tests need some specific additional input.

It could be possible to create different versions of `TestCaseName` with different values of `Params`, but that would duplicate a fair amount of code.

Otherwise, it could be possible to add a single parameter to `Params`, corresponding to a custom `AdditionalInput` class which contains fields for all possible additional input. Extending `TestCaseName` as needed, the setup could be specialized.

Are there better approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: Hard to know what is best solution without seeing some actual code. However make certain you keep your tests simple (you don't want your tests to give wrong results) so at some point duplication might be better then trying to be smart. Maybe you can move the common code to SetUp, TearDown or other function?

Comment: I agree that code duplication might be better. What code exactly would you like to see? (more code for the current implementation or code for the proposed solutions?)